# Which font is used for the Mykerinos logo?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image: Mykerinos logo using sans-serif font]

Identify this sans-serif font anyone?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the font is close to [Myriad Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/myriad/) -

[image]